# Close lids of a SVG Box with CSS animation

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I have been looking at the tutorials and documentation for CSS animations but I cannot figure out how to flip a box lid along a specific axis using CSS on SVG. My goal is to make the lid close one after another on the box. Here are my SVG snippets

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="160.93758mm"
   height="125.50214mm"
   viewBox="0 0 160.93758 125.50215"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5227"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)"
   sodipodi:docname="box.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs5221">
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect6614"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect5176"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect5176-5"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect5176-9"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect6614-4"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect6614-5"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="269.49536"
     inkscape:cy="253.67959"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="960"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="952"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5224">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-18.466661,-171.67717)">
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59225053;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5538"
       width="59.658813"
       height="59.658813"
       x="262.90607"
       y="152.26492"
       transform="matrix(0.89505329,0.4459592,-0.89505329,0.4459592,0,0)" />
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.72032,270.24236 -53.6256,26.67238 -0.065,-58.55462 53.3978,-26.60539 z"
       id="rect5538-0"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 45.338711,270.24235 53.6256,26.67238 0.065,-58.55462 -53.3978,-26.60539 z"
       id="rect5538-0-2"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 99.029711,185.14932 v 53.21079"
       id="path5765"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="south box-lid"
       x="322.62885"
       y="152.47447"
       transform="matrix(0.89526273,0.4455386,-0.89526273,0.4455386,0,0)" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2-6"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="west box-lid"
       x="212.15384"
       y="263.12427"
       transform="matrix(-0.89526273,0.44553859,0.89526273,0.44553859,0,0)" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2-3"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="north box-lid"
       x="233.16525"
       y="152.57962"
       transform="matrix(0.89526273,0.44553859,-0.89526273,0.44553859,0,0)" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2-4"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="east box-lid"
       x="122.65482"
       y="263.08911"
       transform="matrix(-0.89526273,0.44553859,0.89526273,0.44553859,0,0)" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.3244,250.8869 c -6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244"
       id="path6612"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect6614"
       inkscape:original-d="m 152.3244,250.8869 -19.27678,8.88244" />
    <path
       transform="translate(2.0533333e-6,9.5439038)"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.3244,250.8869 c -6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244"
       id="path6612-7"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect6614-4"
       inkscape:original-d="m 152.3244,250.8869 -19.27678,8.88244" />
    <path
       transform="translate(0.03779967,4.7436062)"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.3244,250.8869 c -6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244"
       id="path6612-5"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect6614-5"
       inkscape:original-d="m 152.3244,250.8869 -19.27678,8.88244" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Each lid is a path element whose class is "box-lid" with the respective directional class name. The lids in the north and south lids, at the same time, close before the west and east ones. Furthermore, The lid should be rotated 180 deg along the diagonal axes which are the side of the top of the box. I have looked at the rotate3D function but I could not animate the lids to the desired result. So I am looking forward to the tips and advice and please excuse my bad English.

Comment: Using Javascript, QueryAll your box-lid selectors, then run them through a forEach loop, then add an event listener, maybe click? and pass the event into the function, run conditionals for each side, north, south, east, west, perhaps add data-attributes to your elements?, and change the transform attribute for each iteration to match a new matrix mapped t show the bx lid closing. You could store those new matrix's in an object and use the *side* as the key of the object and the value as the matrix value. Then set the transform attribute using setAttribute().

Comment: @dalelandry thank you for the suggestion, it would help solve my situation greatly.  However, my biggest obstacle is which matrix or transforms function to use to manipulate the lids? I spent a great amount of time on rotate3D() but I can not make the lids rotate about the side that is attached to the top of the box.

Comment: [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67574086/how-to-rotate-svg-in-a-3d-space-with-css) will get you started, but still a lot more work to do yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing path morphing with anime.js and it worked 80% but the layers orders turned out to be a problem. You can see the lid on the south as it closes, the lid is underneath the east lid in the SVG code so the closing looks pretty odd unless I make the animation finish quickly. Is there a way to manipulate SVG layer orders? Here are my codes

```js
   const lidN = {
      path2:"m 98.792632,171.86423 0.04854,13.28552 -53.303611,26.5272 -0.04854,-13.28552 z",
      path3:"m 123.36108,197.37762 -24.519912,-12.22787 -53.303611,26.5272 24.519916,12.22787 z"
   }
   const lidS = {
      path2: "m 152.33287,211.67687 0.0485,-13.73978 -53.303611,26.5272 -0.04853,13.73978 z",
      path3: "m 152.33287,211.67687 -27.54373,-13.73978 -53.303613,26.5272 27.543736,13.73978 z"
   }
   const lidE = {
      path2: "m 99.078269,171.86381 -0.04854,13.28552 53.303611,26.5272 0.0485,-13.28552 z",
      path3: "m 72.419749,198.39294 26.60998,-13.24361 53.303611,26.5272 -26.61002,13.24361 z"
   }
   const lidW = {
      path2: "m 45.631926,211.75474 -0.04853,-16.5746 53.303612,26.5272 0.04853,16.5746 z",
      path3: "m 45.631926,211.75474 26.787779,-13.3618 53.303615,26.5272 -26.787782,13.3618 z"
   }
   window.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      const timeline1 = anime.timeline({
      autoplay: true,
      duration: 500,
   })
   const timeline2 = anime.timeline({
      autoplay: true,
      duration: 500,
   })
    timeline1.add({
       targets: '.lidn',
       d:[
         
         {value: lidN.path2},
         {value: lidN.path3}
       ],
       easing: "linear",
    }).add({
      targets: '.lide',
       d:[
         
         {value: lidE.path2},
         {value: lidE.path3}
       ],
       easing: "linear",
    })
    timeline2.add({
       targets: ".lids",
       d:[
   
         {value: lidS.path2},
         {value: lidS.path3}
       ],
       easing: "linear",
    }).add({
      targets: '.lidw',
       d:[
         
         {value: lidW.path2},
         {value: lidW.path3}
       ],
       easing: "linear",
    })
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="anime.min.js"></script>
   </head>
<body>

   <svg width="160.93758" height="125.50215" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

      <metadata id="metadata5224">image/svg+xml</metadata>
      <g class="layer">
       <title>Layer 1</title>
       <g id="layer1" transform="translate(-18.466661,-171.67717)">
        <path d="m99.02972,185.14932c17.79928,8.86847 35.59855,17.73693 53.39782,26.6054c-17.79927,8.86846 -35.59855,17.73693 -53.39782,26.6054c-17.79928,-8.86847 -35.59855,-17.73693 -53.39782,-26.6054c17.79927,-8.86846 35.59855,-17.73693 53.39782,-26.6054z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect5538" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m152.72032,270.24236c-17.8752,8.89079 -35.7504,17.78159 -53.6256,26.67238c-0.02167,-19.51821 -0.04333,-39.03641 -0.065,-58.55462c17.79927,-8.86846 35.59853,-17.73693 53.3978,-26.60539c0.0976,19.49588 0.1952,38.99175 0.2928,58.48763z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect5538-0" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m45.33871,270.24235c17.8752,8.89079 35.7504,17.78159 53.6256,26.67238c0.02167,-19.51821 0.04333,-39.03641 0.065,-58.55462c-17.79927,-8.86846 -35.59853,-17.73693 -53.3978,-26.60539c-0.0976,19.49588 -0.1952,38.99175 -0.2928,58.48763z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect5538-0-2" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m99.02971,185.14932c0,17.73693 0,35.47386 0,53.21079" fill="none" id="path5765" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m72.14531,171.86423l26.69586,13.28552l-53.30361,26.5272l-26.69586,-13.28552l53.30361,-26.5272z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect5565-2-3" class="lidn" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m152.33287,211.67687l26.69585,13.28552l-53.30361,26.5272l-26.69585,-13.28552l53.30361,-26.5272z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect5565-2" class="lids" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m45.63193,211.75474l-26.69585,13.28552l53.30361,26.5272l26.69585,-13.28552l-53.30361,-26.5272z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect5565-2-6" class="lidw" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m125.72559,171.86381l-26.69586,13.28552l53.30361,26.5272l26.69586,-13.28552l-53.30361,-26.5272z" fill="#ffffff" fill-rule="evenodd" id="rect5565-2-4" class="lide" stroke="#000000" stroke-dashoffset="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>

        <path d="m152.3244,250.8869c-6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244" fill="none" id="path6612" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917"/>
        <path d="m152.3244,250.8869c-6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244" fill="none" id="path6612-7" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917" transform="translate(2.0533333e-6,9.5439038)"/>
        <path d="m152.3244,250.8869c-6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244" fill="none" id="path6612-5" stroke="#000000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-width="0.52917" transform="translate(0.03779967,4.7436062)"/>
       </g>
      </g>
     </svg>


</body>

</html>
```

I used Inkscape to edit the path into two stages, then I copied the values in the d attributes in each stage of the path shape and morph the lid.

Comment: Well done, glad to see you got the outcome you wanted!

Comment: @dalelandry Thank you for the suggestion above as well, It is thorough and well explained.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for an animated closure that shows the tops of the lid ***hinging*** on an axis, however, I will share the outline I gave you in the comments as it may help you to find a solution you are happy with.

I used the ***x axis*** attribute to move the lid to *closed* position using two ***data-set*** attributes and an array of object for ***state*** => `opened` / `closed` and ***side*** `north` / `south` / `east` / `west`.

For the ***data-state*** we add `data-state="opened"` as the initial value for `x`.
For the ***data-side*** we add the `class` defined *side* `north`, `south`, `east` and `west` for each corresponding side.

Then in JavaScript we instantiate and define the array of objects `boxLids` for reference when changing the state of the lids in our callbacks conditional. The callback function has a for loop to iterate over the ***lid*** elements and check each state and side. First we check the `state`, if it is ***opened*** we reference the values using the `data-side` attributes value in the object => `boxLids[0]['closed'][lids[i].dataset.side]`, basically this will be boxLids array => `[0]` then the *state* we want to find the *values* for `['closed']`, then the *side* `[lids[i].dataset.side]` => ***north*** for example. As we are iterating using a *for* *loop* with the *index* each lid element will be iterated over and changed accordingly => `lids[i]`. We set the attributes value using `lids[i].setAttribute('x', sides)` where `sides` = `boxLids[0]['closed'][lids[i].dataset.side]`. Lastly we change the attribute `data-state` using the ***dataset*** property to `closed` => `lids[i].dataset.state = 'closed'`.

Each time one of the ***lids*** is clicked, the event listener is fired and checking the state, changing the state and x attribute according to the `data-state` value set with in the element. If opened, close, if closed, open...

```js
// instantiate an array of objects that defined the state of the box lids in 
// terms of opened and closed, then what the x axis is of each lid
const boxLids = [{
  "closed": {
    "north": "263.16525",
    "west": "182.15384",
    "south": "292.62885",
    "east": "152.65482"
  },
  "opened": {
    "north": "233.16525",
    "west": "212.15384",
    "south": "322.62885",
    "east": "122.65482"
  }
}]
// get all nodes with the class selector of .box-lids
const lids = document.querySelectorAll('.box-lid')

// call back for the event listener
function closeLids() {
  // iterate over each element in the nodeList using for loop
  for (let i = 0; i < lids.length; i++) {
    // consitional to see the "state" of the lids "opened" or "closed"
    if (lids[i].dataset.state === 'opened') {
      // if data.state === opened we close each lid by setting the 
      // x attribute in the rect element to the closed state from 
      // the array of objects
      let sides = boxLids[0]['closed'][lids[i].dataset.side]      
      lids[i].setAttribute('x', sides)
      // make sure to set the data attribute of data-state to closed
      lids[i].dataset.state = 'closed'
    } else {
      // else the state is closed so lets open each lid using the
      // object state opened values for each side
      let sides = boxLids[0]['opened'][lids[i].dataset.side]
      lids[i].setAttribute('x', sides)
      // make sure to reset the data attribute of data-state to opened
      lids[i].dataset.state = 'opened'
    }
  }
}

// iterate over each node and perform an event for click
lids.forEach(lid => {
  // pass in the callback function closeLids
  lid.addEventListener('click', closeLids)
})
```

```css
.east {
  transition: all 50ms ease-out;
}

.west {
  transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}

.north {
  transition: all 150ms ease-out;
}

.south {
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
  xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" width="160.93758mm" height="125.50214mm" viewBox="0 0 160.93758 125.50215" version="1.1" id="svg5227" inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)" sodipodi:docname="box.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs5221">
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect6614"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect5176"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect5176-5"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect5176-9"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect6614-4"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="simplify"
       id="path-effect6614-5"
       is_visible="true"
       steps="1"
       threshold="0.000859316"
       smooth_angles="360"
       helper_size="0"
       simplify_individual_paths="false"
       simplify_just_coalesce="false"
       simplifyindividualpaths="false"
       simplifyJustCoalesce="false" />
  </defs>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.7"
     inkscape:cx="269.49536"
     inkscape:cy="253.67959"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:window-width="960"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="952"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5224">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-18.466661,-171.67717)">
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59225053;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5538"
       width="59.658813"
       height="59.658813"
       x="262.90607"
       y="152.26492"
       transform="matrix(0.89505329,0.4459592,-0.89505329,0.4459592,0,0)" />
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.72032,270.24236 -53.6256,26.67238 -0.065,-58.55462 53.3978,-26.60539 z"
       id="rect5538-0"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
    <path
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 45.338711,270.24235 53.6256,26.67238 0.065,-58.55462 -53.3978,-26.60539 z"
       id="rect5538-0-2"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccc" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 99.029711,185.14932 v 53.21079"
       id="path5765"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />    
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2-6"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="west box-lid"
       data-side="west"
       data-state="opened"
       x="212.15384" 
       y="263.12427"
       transform="matrix(-0.89526273,0.44553859,0.89526273,0.44553859,0,0)" />    
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2-4"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="east box-lid"
       data-side="east"
       data-state="opened"
       x="122.65482" 
       y="263.08911"
       transform="matrix(-0.89526273,0.44553859,0.89526273,0.44553859,0,0)" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="south box-lid"
       data-side="south"
       data-state="opened"
       x="322.62885" 
       y="152.47447"
       transform="matrix(0.89526273,0.4455386,-0.89526273,0.4455386,0,0)" />
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.59246069;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect5565-2-3"
       width="29.819016"
       height="59.539631"
       class="north box-lid"
       data-side="north"
       data-state="opened"
       x="233.16525" 
       y="152.57962"
       transform="matrix(0.89526273,0.44553859,-0.89526273,0.44553859,0,0)" />
    <path
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.3244,250.8869 c -6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244"
       id="path6612"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect6614"
       inkscape:original-d="m 152.3244,250.8869 -19.27678,8.88244" />
    <path
       transform="translate(2.0533333e-6,9.5439038)"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.3244,250.8869 c -6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244"
       id="path6612-7"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect6614-4"
       inkscape:original-d="m 152.3244,250.8869 -19.27678,8.88244" />
    <path
       transform="translate(0.03779967,4.7436062)"
       style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5291667;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 152.3244,250.8869 c -6.42559,2.96081 -12.85119,5.92163 -19.27678,8.88244"
       id="path6612-5"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:path-effect="#path-effect6614-5"
       inkscape:original-d="m 152.3244,250.8869 -19.27678,8.88244" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's nice! What about adding some eassing to make the closure more slow and consistent?

Comment: @SIMBIOSIS you could place an offsetting transition on the lids using CSS. Check out my edit.

Comment: You know, I have a unanswered bountied question and maybe, comes to my mind, you know what to do to solve it. Could you check it please?!

Comment: I can take a look at it see what I can do. What is the link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68214169/objects-snap-to-custum-grid-on-fabric-js

Comment: That is brilliant, that would be more thoroughly explained your advice in the comment section above. I highly appreciate your help. and actually, I came up with using path morphing with SVG animation library anime.js. I would post my answer later @dalelandry may be you can have a look at it as well?